# How to only read one line (its head) from a file?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to get the head of a file. How to only read one line (its head) from a file? (spring-batch)

Comment: By Head do you mean the first line?  What kind of file? (txt, xls, etc...)  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use  [FlatFileItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html).

In such case it possible to set [setLinesToSkip(1)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html#setLinesToSkip%28int%29) to skip header and use [setSkippedLinesCallback](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html#setSkippedLinesCallback%28org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineCallbackHandler%29) to get its value. If you want to ignore other lines - just alwasy return `null` in [LineMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html#setLineMapper%28org.springframework.batch.item.file.LineMapper%29).

But if you really need only one line - implement your [Tasklet](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html) or [ItemReader](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html) for it.